# Has no exported member Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

[why red squiggly error ]
**Error in visual stdio**   
[error screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2GrX.png)

> '"/Users/dev/pratice_workspace/quickstart/src/app/components/language.component"'
>   has no exported member 'LangugeComponent'. import LangugeComponent

**Error in the chrome console**

> ZoneAwareError __zone_symbol__error : Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected
>   value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule' Error: Unexpected
>   value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule' at
>   SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LangugeComponent } from './components/language.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LangugeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

language.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'language',
    template: `
  <h1>Hello</h1>

  `,
})
export class LanguageComponent {
    name = 'Sandeep';
    designation = 'SE'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have typo in `app.module.ts`

```
import { LangugeComponent } from './components/language.component'

declarations: [AppComponent, LangugeComponent]`
```

should be

```
import { LanguageComponent } from './components/language.component'

declarations: [AppComponent, LanguageComponent]`
```

Comment: No worries, been there a bunch of times, thats why it looked so familiar :) If you ever see the "has no exported member" error check that you're exporting and importing properly